# Scene Builder - Custom Control Reuse

Tags: javafx, dependencies, custom-controls, fxml, scenebuilder

I've been at this problem trying to find workarounds for weeks now and I am starting to give up. I must be doing something fundamentally wrong. Anyway, this is my situation. I have previously made a neat little program using JavaFX but have now discovered Scene Builder and want to build it all again using this tool. The project includes several components that are frequently reused such as the one below. This is made up of a label, a slider, a text field and another custom component, an InfoIcon.

[image]

I have understood that the done thing is to import the custom component (the InfoIcon) as a .jar file into Scene Builder when building my SliderVariable as I call it. This works great and I can run a small demo of my SliderVariable from within Eclipse by creating a main method, a scene and making a SliderVariable in this scene. As mentioned this works great. Importing or Including the InfoIcon does not do what I want (I don't think) because then I cannot easily make changes to the InfoIcon (or its controller) and update my SliderVariable and then see the effects in the final product.

The problems arise when I want to take it one step further and in turn use my SliderVariable in Scene Builder. I do as with the InfoIcon. I export my slider variable to a non-executable jar and then import it into Scene Builder. Here Scene Builder complains that it cannot find any UI components and thus fails to import it. I have discovered that this is because when I export the SliderVariable as a jar it does not also package its dependencies meaning the InfoIcon doesn't get bundled with it and that the compiler cannot find this component as I try to use it.

I have tried to solve this with FatJar which I cannot get working (and it seems like it is not in use any more). I have tried Maven where I couldn't import the Maven project dependency of the InfoIcon in the FXML of the SliderVariable. Finally I have also tried simply not importing a jar but instead including the source code of InfoIcon in a separate package of SliderVariable but then I couldn't import it into my FXML. I am desperate. What do people normally do if they want to reuse custom components with their own controllers in Scene Builder? Is this even done? Should I just give up :'(?

This unwieldly post must be highly confusing but I do not know how to make it clearer. Any sort of response would be greatly appreciated and if you do not believe this forum is the right place to post something like this (which it probably isn't) please point me to someplace else where I am more welcome.

Many thanks.

EDIT 1: I have now added a folder in my project called Dependencies. In here I put a copy (not a reference to) my InfoIcon.jar.

[image]

I then add this .jar file to my Build Path and remove the old one. I then enter SceneBuilder and reimport the InfoIcon jar but this time from the Dependencies folder I just created. At this point the small project test I've made still runs fine. I then export as JAR file with the following settings and hit finish.

[image]

I then try to import it into Scene Builder and Scene Builder tells me it cannot find any UI components.

EDIT 2: Should I select these items?

[image]

Note that the jar file is in Dependencies but also in Referenced Libraries (which is not visible here). This type of selection makes it so that Scene Builder can find and Import the InfoIcon but not the SliderVariable.

Comment: You need to select the project itself, you are exporting only `InfoIcon` like this. You may need to select `application` package for it to work.

Comment: @Jai You mean I should select the application package within the InfoIcon project? Because that doesn't work either. It finishes with warnings.

Comment: Select both application package and the JAR file.

Comment: @Jai as in my second edit?

Answer (score 0):

When you export `InfoIcon`, you can simply select the packages and classes related to it in the Eclipse's package explorer (or other similar explorer views), and choose export.

Similarly, when you try to export `SliderVariable` control, you need to choose everything you have selected in `InfoIcon`, on top of other files that are needed by `SliderVariable` control itself.

If `InfoIcon` is imported into `SliderVariable` project as a JAR file, then you would need to manually select that JAR file during the export of `SliderVariable`.

Comment: Yes it is imported as a JAR. How do I go about selecting this? I cannot seem to access the referenced libraries folder within the export wizard.

Comment: @IvarEriksson Create a separate folder in the project and put the JAR file there, then right-click it and add that to the build path. That way, you would be able to see the JAR file during export wizard.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Now I can select the JAR in the export wizard at least. I will update my question with exactly what I am doing.